# Returning a nested view inside a map

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, lodash

Hello this is my parent component code

```
renderMenu() {
if (this.props.menu) {
  return (
    <List menu={this.props.menu} />
  );
}
}
render() {
  console.log(this.props);
  const { ContainerStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={ContainerStyle}>
      {this.renderRestaurantName()}
        <ScrollView>
        {this.renderSpinner()}
        {this.renderMenu()}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
}
```

Inside List I return a view nested in map
List.js =>

```
renderItem() {
return (
  this.props.menu.map(({ name, items }) => {
      <View>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
      </View>
      {
        items.map((resp) => {
          return (
          <View>
            <Text>{resp.title}</Text>
          </View>
        );
        });
      }
  })
 );
 }
render() {
return (
  <View>
  {this.renderItem()}
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Nothing appears on screen even though i can see content using console.log. What am I doing wrong here? 
Also should I use something else to parse the JSON?

Also this is the JSON data
[image: JSON Data]

Am I parsing it correctly?

Comment: Can you put your ```List.js``` file here?

Comment: hey, sorry, I added the whole file now.

Comment: Check @mayank-shukla response.

Answer (score 2):

If the menu has a data structure similar to this:

```js
const menu = [
  { name: 'name 1', items: [{ title: 't1' }, { title: 't2' }] },
  { name: 'name 2', items: [{ title: 't1' }, { title: 't2' }] },
  { name: 'name 3', items: [{ title: 't1' }, { title: 't2' }] },
  ];

You could do something like this to render nested objects:

const menuListComponent = () => (
  <View>
    {
      this.props.menu.map(menuItem => (
        <View key={menuItem.name}>
          <Text>{menuItem.name}</Text>
          {
            menuItem.items.map(item => (
              <View key={item.title}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
            ))
          }
        </View>
      ))
    }
  </View>
);
```

Just make sure to use the correct key value.

**Note:**
This is not the most efficient way in React-Native. It takes time and memory to render the entire list initially.
If you have a long list or more complex data, `FlatList` should be the better choice https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: This works! but since this is a const would I be able to use reducers here to register onPress for Touchablewithoutfeedback for the name property i.e. name1, name2, etc in example, and thus expand the item list for that particular name?

Comment: Good on you. I'm not fully understand what you mean. But, if you like to make the inner item clickable, please consider this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/7wwl0oj96 It's exactly the same concept. Once replacing html components to React-Native components, this should works on native app.

Comment: Notice how I bind the inner item with `onClick` event (`onPress` for Native, same thing) DO NOT use arrow function inside map, it will create new function instance for each item, which slow down the performance dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to display the list is to use FlatList 
[Read docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

You can use it this way:

```
render(){
    return(
        <FlatList
              data={this.props.menu}
              renderItem={({item})=>this._renderListMenu(item)}
              keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index}
         />
    )
}

 _renderListMenu(item){
    return <MyMenu Menu={item} />
}
```

in other class (MyMenu):

```
export default class MyMenu extends Component{
render(){
    const {name , items } = this.props.Menu;
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={items}
              renderItem={({item})=>this._renderListItem(item)}
              keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
_renderListItem(item){
     return <MyItem item={item}/>
}
}
```

and you create MyItem class Like the above example

Comment: But I want every category to expand item list conditionally, i.e. onClick, using reducer, will using flat list work this way by nesting components inside components

Comment: You can use `Touchable` in the `MyMenu` Component and implement everything you need. flatList is very flexible

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the resultant array from function, also returning the View from nested map body but forgot to return inside first map body.

Write it like this:

```
renderItem() {
  return (
    this.props.menu.map(({ name, items }) => {
      return (           // => here
         <View>
           <Text>{name}</Text>
           {items.map((resp) => <View> <Text>{resp.title}</Text> </View>)}
         </View>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

Or remove `{}` and use `()`:

```
renderItem() {
  return (
    this.props.menu.map(({ name, items }) => (       // or use ( and remove {
        <View>
          <Text>{name}</Text>
          {items.map((resp) => <View> <Text>{resp.title}</Text> </View>)}
        </View>
    ))
  )
}
```

Another issue is, you are returning multiple children, so put the map part inside the View.

Comment: Hey, I'm confused what difference would that make? using ( instead of {

Comment: diff is first map is returning undefined in your case.

Comment: Using the second code I get a unexpected token error while adding the other map function inside curly braces. Also I think I have a return statement inside renderItem at the top.

Comment: It gives me an error Raw text cannot be used outside of a <Text> tag. Also I would like to render this like a drop down list where if someone clicks on Pizza they might see both kind of pizza. I will later add ownProps property for that but apart from that is JSON rendering okay for that here?